# complex sql helps

Tags: sql

I have following tables:

Orders & Payments.

When user makes an order, record inserts on Orders. & if payment is successful then its OrderID is saved within Payments table.

Table Structure:

**Orders** : OrderID, OrderAmt ....
**Payment**: PaymentID, PaymentOrderID, PaymentStatus..

Now if a user cancel the payment process, the record on Order is added. but not on Payments.
Now if i want a list Orders without Payments, what can be the sql here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select o.* from Orders o
where not exists (
  select 1 from Payment
  where PaymentOrderID = o.OrderID
)
```

or with a `LEFT` join of `Orders` to `Payment` which will return only the orders that do not have a match in the table `Payment`:

```
select o.*
from Orders o left join Payment p
on p.PaymentOrderID = o.OrderID
where p.PaymentID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is a subquery if you want the columns of only orders table

```
     Select * from orders where
       PaymentOrderId is Null or 
        PaymentOrderId
        In (Select paymentOrderid from 
         payments
         Where paymentstatus='Not Paid')
```